# Prove that $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm

Tags: normed-spaces

I am in a pickle. I'm given the following info:

Let us define a function $f(t)=a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)$ where $a,b\in\mathbb C$. Defin the norm:

$$
\|f\|=\|a\cos(t)+b\sin(t)\|=\sqrt{|a|^2+|b|^2}
$$

I am unable to prove the triangle inequality for the above norm:

$$\forall f_1,f_2,\|f_1+f_2\|\le\|f_1\|+\|f_2\|$$

I understand that Cauchy-Schwarz inequality must be applied, but I have not had success thus far. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: Are all functions of the form $a\cos(t) + b\sin(t)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb C$?

Comment: @danielson Yes, all of them are

Comment: Isn't it basically proving that $\lVert\cdot\rVert_2$ is a norm on $\mathbb{C}^2$? The norm of your function is defined as the $2$-norm of the vector of its coefficients $a,b$.

Comment: Maybe, but I'm not able to formulate the Cauchy-Schwarz part where you have to do some trick with the $2|a_1||a_2|$ and $2|b_1||b_2|$ terms that appear. I guess my problem is I'm not sure what the inner product $<f_1,f_2>$ is...

Comment: See it as the norm on $\mathbb{C}^2$ hinted above, then: [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HermitianInnerProduct.html) may help.

Comment: @ClementC. it is not working. The problem in on $\mathbb R^2$ we have $<u,v>=<v,u>$ but for complex numbers $<a,b>=\overline{<b,a>}$. So what I get is:
$$
\|f_1+f_2\|^2=\|f_1\|^2+\|f_2\|^2+<f_1,f_2>+\overline{<f_1,f_2>}
$$
Which I do not know how to manipulate in order to get $\|f_1+f_2\|^2\le\|f_1\|^2+\|f_2\|^2$

Comment: Ok, I got it:
$$
\|f_1+f_2\|^2=\|f_1\|^2+\|f_2\|^2+<f_1,f_2>+<f_2,f_1>
$$
$$
\|f_1+f_2\|^2\le\|f_1\|^2+\|f_2\|^2+\|f_1\|\|f_2\|+\|f_2\|\|f_1\|
$$
$$
\|f_1+f_2\|^2=\|f_1\|^2+\|f_2\|^2+2\|f_1\|\|f_2\|
$$
$$
\|f_1+f_2\|^2=(\|f_1\|+\|f_2\|)^2
$$
$$
\Rightarrow \|f_1+f_2\|^2\le\|f_1\|+\|f_2\|
$$

Comment: Re the previous comment: the latter is not what you should prove. The RHS will have to be $(\lVert f_1\rVert+\lVert f_2\rVert)^2$. (as your last comment shows, this does hold)